# Загрузка значений в select

Tags: php7

А обязательно скрипт подключения значений должен быть в том же php, что и основная страничка?

В селекторе вылезла такая надпись "Trying to access array offset on value of type null". Это получается $row1 пустой?

Поле селектора в основной страничке.

```
<select>
<?php
require_once('s_num_car.php');
  while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($zapros1)) 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row1[5]; ?></option>
</select>
```

Скрипт получения значений для селектора.

```
<?php
require_once('c.php');

$sql="select * from cars";
$zapros1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

Скрип соединения.

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','rotokan123rot');
define('DB','auto_to_db');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die ('Unable to Connect');

if(!$con)
{
echo 'Connection error == '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
echo "OK";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл такой код и он работает.

```
<select name="box1">
<?php
  require_once('s_num_car.php');
  while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($zapros1))
  {
    print '<option value="'.$row1[0].'">'.$row1[5].'</option>';
  }
?>
```